# Find $V_c(t)$ for the given equation and initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find $V_c (t)$ that satisfies the following equation and initial conditions
$$\frac{d^2V_c(t)}{dt^2} + 10 \frac{dV_c(t)}{dt} + 125V_c (t) =250u(t),$$ 
$$ V_c(0) =0v,\quad   \frac{dV_c(0)}{dt}=25\frac{V}{S}$$

Comment: Why not show us what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Hints: It looks like you are working with Laplace transforms.

We have:

$$\dfrac{d^2V_c(t)}{dt^2} + 10 \frac{dV_c(t)}{dt} + 125V_c (t) = 250u(t),$$ 
$$ V_c(0) =0v,\quad   \frac{dV_c(0)}{dt}=25\frac{V}{S}$$

- $\mathscr{L}\left(\dfrac{d^2V_c(t)}{dt^2} \right) = s^2 V_c(s) - sV_c(0) - V_c'(0)$
- $\mathscr{L}\left(10 \frac{dV_c(t)}{dt} \right) = 10(sV_c(s) - V_c(0))$
- $\mathscr{L}\left(125V_c (t) \right) = 125 V_c(s)$
- $\mathscr{L}\left(250u(t) \right) = \dfrac{250}{s}$

Now, substitute the initial conditions above, solve for $V_c(s)$ on the LSH, expand the RHS using partial fractions and then find the $\mathscr{L}^{-1}$ to find $V_c(t)$.